# Why Insect bites are itchy rather than pain?

Tags: entomology

i don't understand if some thing bites or hurt we feel pain, but its differ for [insect bites](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=insect%20bites&oq=insect%20bites&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), why so?

Comment: maybe because those bites cause allergic reaction

Comment: Has a wasp ever stung you? It is quite painful

Answer (score 1):

> You're more likely to have an allergic reaction if you're stung by an insect. The reaction can be classed as:
>
> **Minor localised reaction** – this is normal and doesn't require allergy testing, although the affected area will often be painful for
>   a few days
>
> **large localised reaction (LLR)** – this can cause other symptoms, such as swelling, itching and a rash
>
> **systemic reaction (SR)** – this often requires immediate medical attention because it can cause a potentially life-threatening allergic
>   reaction (anaphylaxis)

Taken from : http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Bites-insect/Pages/Symptoms.aspx

You can read up on this here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflammation

http://primer.crohn.ie/the-inflammatory-response

For a more detailed look, I would suggest papers like this:

*Loza, Matthew J., et al. "Assembly of inflammation-related genes for pathway-focused genetic analysis." PLoS One 2.10 (2007): e1035.*

or a good immunology textbook.